# Phonegap Zip plugin FileNotFoundException

Tags: cordova, zip, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), with this set of plugins:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.0.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.2" />
<gap:plugin name="org.chromium.zip" version="1.0.0" />
```

I just want to unzip a file which is in the persistent directory, to a temporary folder. Since it was firing a `FileNotFoundException` error, I added a new line to create that folder before unzipping it. Although console log shows the recently created folder name, the same error is still raising.

Here is the code:

```
var relativeFilePath = "Mydir/myfile.zip";
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function (fs){
        var entry=fs.root; 
        entry.getDirectory("Destination", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dir){
            console.log("Created dir "+dir.name); 
            zip.unzip(fileSystem.root.toURL() + relativeFilePath, fs.root.toURL() + 'Destination/', function(){
                alert("unzipped!");
            });
        },function(error){
              alert(error.code);
        });
     },function(err){
          alert(err.code);
     });
    },function(err){
         alert(err.code);
});
```

Error traceback:

```
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711): Doesn't exist
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711): An error occurred while unzipping.
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File: "cdvfile://localhost/temporary/Destination/" not found
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711):   at org.apache.cordova.Zip.unzipSync(Zip.java:57)
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711):   at org.apache.cordova.Zip.access$000(Zip.java:19)
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711):   at org.apache.cordova.Zip$1.run(Zip.java:35)
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-03 11:42:32.039: E/Zip(12711):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I can make it work from the comand line with cordova using [this newer zip plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip). But I can't use it, while this version is not included in the Phonegap Build [plugin repository](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/727).

How could I fix this issue, or even better, would it be possible to use last mentioned plugin with Phonegap Build?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [new zip plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1071) which can be used with phonegap build. This solves the problem.